# Analyzing the crystal frequency (Bus Clock Frequency) of a HCS12 Microcontroller using an Oscilloscope

Tags: microcontroller, frequency, oscilloscope, freescale

I have an HCS12 Mircocontroller and I would like to capture the crystal frequency from the bus clock on a oscilloscope.

How do I find out where I should connect my probes on the board to analyze this signal on the oscilloscope? I would like to measure the actual crystal frequency before it is divided by 2 or hits any pre-scaled division.

I realize this is a broad question but does anyone have any general guidance to what I should look for to figuring this out.

[TWRS12G128](http://www.axman.com/content/twr-s12g128)

Comment: Do you think the crystal is exhibiting a problem?

Comment: Honestly i'm having a hard time find out what the crystal frequency is. I'm looking at the data sheet that came with it but it's not telling me what the crystal frequency is

Comment: A link would help

Comment: How can I add a pdf document on here

Comment: Copy and paste the hyperlink into the question area.

Comment: Posted the hyperlink above "TWRS12G128"

Comment: In the future, you can usually find this information on the schematic (it worked in this case), in the parts list or BOM, or often the frequency will be stamped on top of the crystal or oscillator.

Answer (score 2):

This MCU has the typical Pierce oscillator configuration.

Based on your schematic, if you attach a scope probe (use 10:1) onto pin 14, you should see an 8MHz periodic waveform. It won't be a square wave but it should be fairly large.

[image: excerpt from schematic that clearly states the crystal frequency]

You might also see something similar on pin 12, but without an FET probe it may not be right because the scope probe will disturb the load capacitance on the crystal.